# Bash & SVN: How to handle when the SVN command wants user feedback?

Tags: bash, svn

So, I'm working on a bash script to manage some of my version control commands that I've been doing manually via the command line. It's a long story why I'm doing this, and not just using one of the SVN tools out there. Short answer: I'm using both Git and SVN, with the same codebase, but for different purposes. These scripts allow me to execute all the commands at once.

Anyway, I've got the script going great. Everything works perfectly. My one concern is the times that SVN prompts the user for input. The big one I'm thinking about is merge conflicts. Whenever there's a conflict when its downloading files from the server, it prompts the user to take action about that conflict.

Ideally, I want to suppress all output from the SVN command during execution, and if there are merge conflicts, just postpone them and then tell the user at the end that such conflicts exist (the user can then go in and resolve them).

So, for the question: Is there a way to use bash to handle those user input prompts. To detect them, respond to them, and keep the process going?

For the sake of argument, let's work off of this simple SVN command. Assume that this command is in a Bash script, and when it is executed there is a merge conflict. What, if anything, can I do?

```
svn update .
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the

```
svn update my_checkout_path --accept postpone --config-option config:miscellany:preserved-conflict-file-exts=*
```

Where `--accept postpone` is to skip all auto conflict operations, and `preserved-conflict-file-exts` is to dissallow auto merge for all files.

Read more:

- http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve.pending
- http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.confarea.html

**Update**

To detect the conflict situation you can look for `Summary of conflicts` string in `update` output (if you sure you have use the english version).

Comment: Awesome, that is great. Is there any way, through a status code or something, to have bash detect whether a conflict exists when it's done? I guess I could do svn status again and search the text for the C marker, but I'm hoping for a higher performing way to do this (ie, not have to query the repository again)